# python json data in tuple format not parsable

Tags: python, json

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following output, which is supposed to be json format, and is generated from a datbase query, isnt parsable.

```
dbresponse = """
(('{"stopApprovalInd":true,"nonPersonalizedCardLine3":"Valued Cardholder","productRoutingBins":[{"requestType":"DIGITAL_ACCOUNT_REQUEST","bin":"342010002"}],"holdtimeSeconds":0,"defaultUpcInd":"false","updatedTimestamp":"2019-01-23T18:53:26.261Z","productName":"PB EGIFT (CAG) MAYO\'S $100","reloadMaxAmount":0,"issuerCompanyCode":"BKPB","updaterId":"IIKIFFFFFFPDZ0PDNQBGWMVGMRVTK9DM","sellStartDate":"2018-08-20T00:00:00.000+0000","taxIncludedInd":false,"taxPercent":0,"maxValueAmount":100,"proxyCardLength":19,"inventorySource":"BLAST","postReversalInd":false,"distributionChannel":"DIGITAL","multicardFlag":"N","companyCode":"BKPB","indentDataType":"0","activateOnShipment":"false","productRedemptionMethods":[],"upc":"07675030446","productFees":[{"feeAmount":0,"feeType":"PURCHASE"},{"feeAmount":0,"feeType":"TRANSACTION"},{"feeAmount":0,"feeType":"CUSTOMIZATION"}],"cpDivisionId":"2X2A9M5KRLXQWQ1SB","subGroupId":"YVAAN33PV7MZ3Z49V0F0J","defaultProductConfigurationId":"Y56X4RXNCY2R9ACSDH","isContentEnabled":false,"productFulfillments":[{"fulfillmentMethod":"EMAIL","fulfillmentType":"PRINT_ON_DEMAND"}],"taxAmount":0,"redeemLocationInd":false,"taxableInd":false,"productRedemptionLocations":[],"generationType":"0","serviceCode":"121","processorCompanyCode":"HP","productDisplayname":"MAYO\'s $100 eGift","baseValueAmount":100,"creatorId":"IIKIFFFFFFPDZ0PDNQBGWMVGMRVTK9DM","subsequentActivation":false,"generateProxyCardNumberInd":false,"productCategory":"CLOSELOOP","exclusionInd":false,"reloadableInd":false,"reversibleInd":false,"productLocale":[{"redemptionInstructions":"<p>Your E-gift Card is redeemable online at mayo.com and in \'s stores nationwide.<\\/p>","productTemplates":[{"templateType":"PRODUCTION","templateId":"Z6WSTWN9HABX8","templatePath":"https://blahblah.net/gcmimages/View/WGNX8/index.html"}],"localeCode":"en_US","inStoreInstructions":"<p>In Store: Print this entire page, and present it to a Mayo\'s Associate at checkout.<\\/p>","onlineInstructions":"<p>Online: Enter your E-Gift Card Number at checkout in the PAY WITH GIFT CARD box. If you have any questions, or to check your balance, please call 1-800-511-2752.<br>You may also scan your printed barcode at a price checker terminal in stores.<br>Your Mayo\'s E-Gift Card number is required for all inquiries.<\\/p>","productDescription":"Mayo\'s, the largest retail brand of Mayo\'s, Inc. (NYSE:M), delivers fashion and affordable luxury to customers at approximately 670 locations in 45 states, the District of Columbia, Puerto Rico and Guam, as well as to customers in the U.S. and more than 100 international destinations through its leading online store at macys.com. Via its stores, e-commerce site, mobile and social platforms, Mayo\'s offers distinctive assortments including the most desired family of exclusive and fashion brands for him, her and home. Mayo\'s is known for such epic events as Mayo\'s 4th of July Fireworks\xae and the Mayo\'s Thanksgiving Day Parade\xae. Building on a more than 150-year tradition, and with the collective support of customers and employees, Mayo\'s helps strengthen communities by supporting local and national charities giving more than $69 million each year to help make a difference in the lives of our customers","termsAndConditions":"Your Mayo\'s E-Gift Card number may be used to purchase any merchandise on-line at macys.com or in-store by following the instructions in the E-Gift Card email. You may not add value back onto the E-Gift Card, nor redeem it for cash or apply it as payment or credit to your credit card account. When you make a purchase with your E-Gift Card number, the value of your purchase plus any shipping/handling fees and sales tax, if applicable, will be automatically deducted from your \\"open to buy.\\" You may check any remaining value via the online Balance Inquiry function, or in-store by scanning the barcode at a price checker terminal or by calling 1-800-511-2752. Please safeguard your Mayo\'s E-Gift Card number. The bearer is responsible for its loss or theft. If your E-Gift Card is lost or stolen, and you have proof of purchase, we will issue you a replacement for the balance shown on our records. Your macys.com E-Gift Card number is required for all inquiries."}],"cardExpirationType":"0","productBarcodes":[{"barcodeType":"1D-CA128"}],"feeStrippingInd":false,"productLineId":"3G2D6R3YG85WZ570","createdTimestamp":"2018-08-20T18:53:46.435Z","inventoryLoadType":"HOT","variableInd":false,"isForcedResponseProduct":false,"reloadMinAmount":0,"entityId":"6APACRYFLXTLSKS","itemBuyerGroupId":"FASHION","provisioningType":"DIGITAL","productFulfillmentPartners":[],"currencyCode":"USD","proxyBin":"0"}',),)
"""
```

I cant treat it like a json because when I do a `type(dbresponse)` on the data (directly from the database), python tells me its a "tuple" data.  But I know in order for me to be able to access the values, python needs to see the data as a `dict`.

I have tried converting it multiple different ways, all to no avail.

```
str(dbresponse)
eval(dict(dbresponse))
str(list(dbresponse)) # tried to convert it to a list, then to a str in hopes of then being able to convert it to dictionary. didnt work.
```

I dont know much about json.

My question is, is there a foolproof way to turn/convert the above data from tuple to dictionary?  And once that is done, how do i iterate through all the keys/values in the data so I see what is available.

I tried `pprinnt` (pretty print) but that isn't so clear to me (i could be using it incorrectly).

Comment: can you paste a line you use to get this data from db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your response really is a string as shown here, and always has the same format, you could remove the `(('` at the start and `',),)` at the end. The rest is a valid JSON string:

```
import json

dbresponse = """(('{"stopApprovalInd":true,"nonPersonalizedCardLine3":"Valued Cardholder","productRoutingBins":[{"requestType":"DIGITAL_ACCOUNT_REQUEST","bin":"342010002"}],"holdtimeSeconds":0,"defaultUpcInd":"false","updatedTimestamp":"2019-01-23T18:53:26.261Z","productName":"PB EGIFT (CASHSTAR) MACY\'S $100","reloadMaxAmount":0,"issuerCompanyCode":"BKPB","updaterId":"IIKIFFFFFFPDZ0PDNQBGWMVGMRVTK9DM","sellStartDate":"2018-08-20T00:00:00.000+0000","taxIncludedInd":false,"taxPercent":0,"maxValueAmount":100,"proxyCardLength":19,"inventorySource":"BLAST","postReversalInd":false,"distributionChannel":"DIGITAL","multicardFlag":"N","companyCode":"BKPB","indentDataType":"0","activateOnShipment":"false","productRedemptionMethods":[],"upc":"07675030446","productFees":[{"feeAmount":0,"feeType":"PURCHASE"},{"feeAmount":0,"feeType":"TRANSACTION"},{"feeAmount":0,"feeType":"CUSTOMIZATION"}],"cpDivisionId":"2X2A9M5KRLXQWQ1SB","subGroupId":"YVAAN33PV7MZ3Z49V0F0J","defaultProductConfigurationId":"Y56X4RXNCY2R9ACSDH","isContentEnabled":false,"productFulfillments":[{"fulfillmentMethod":"EMAIL","fulfillmentType":"PRINT_ON_DEMAND"}],"taxAmount":0,"redeemLocationInd":false,"taxableInd":false,"productRedemptionLocations":[],"generationType":"0","serviceCode":"121","processorCompanyCode":"HP","productDisplayname":"Macy\'s $100 eGift","baseValueAmount":100,"creatorId":"IIKIFFFFFFPDZ0PDNQBGWMVGMRVTK9DM","subsequentActivation":false,"generateProxyCardNumberInd":false,"productCategory":"CLOSELOOP","exclusionInd":false,"reloadableInd":false,"reversibleInd":false,"productLocale":[{"redemptionInstructions":"<p>Your E-gift Card is redeemable online at macys.com and in Macy\'s stores nationwide.<\\/p>","productTemplates":[{"templateType":"PRODUCTION","templateId":"Z6WSTWN9HABX8","templatePath":"https://blahblah.net/gcmimages/View/WGNX8/index.html"}],"localeCode":"en_US","inStoreInstructions":"<p>In Store: Print this entire page, and present it to a Macy\'s Associate at checkout.<\\/p>","onlineInstructions":"<p>Online: Enter your E-Gift Card Number at checkout in the PAY WITH GIFT CARD box. If you have any questions, or to check your balance, please call 1-800-511-2752.<br>You may also scan your printed barcode at a price checker terminal in stores.<br>Your Macy\'s E-Gift Card number is required for all inquiries.<\\/p>","productDescription":"Macy\'s, the largest retail brand of Macy\'s, Inc. (NYSE:M), delivers fashion and affordable luxury to customers at approximately 670 locations in 45 states, the District of Columbia, Puerto Rico and Guam, as well as to customers in the U.S. and more than 100 international destinations through its leading online store at macys.com. Via its stores, e-commerce site, mobile and social platforms, Macy\'s offers distinctive assortments including the most desired family of exclusive and fashion brands for him, her and home. Macy\'s is known for such epic events as Macy\'s 4th of July Fireworks\xae and the Macy\'s Thanksgiving Day Parade\xae. Building on a more than 150-year tradition, and with the collective support of customers and employees, Macy\'s helps strengthen communities by supporting local and national charities giving more than $69 million each year to help make a difference in the lives of our customers","termsAndConditions":"Your Macy\'s E-Gift Card number may be used to purchase any merchandise on-line at macys.com or in-store by following the instructions in the E-Gift Card email. You may not add value back onto the E-Gift Card, nor redeem it for cash or apply it as payment or credit to your credit card account. When you make a purchase with your E-Gift Card number, the value of your purchase plus any shipping/handling fees and sales tax, if applicable, will be automatically deducted from your \\"open to buy.\\" You may check any remaining value via the online Balance Inquiry function, or in-store by scanning the barcode at a price checker terminal or by calling 1-800-511-2752. Please safeguard your Macy\'s E-Gift Card number. The bearer is responsible for its loss or theft. If your E-Gift Card is lost or stolen, and you have proof of purchase, we will issue you a replacement for the balance shown on our records. Your macys.com E-Gift Card number is required for all inquiries."}],"cardExpirationType":"0","productBarcodes":[{"barcodeType":"1D-CA128"}],"feeStrippingInd":false,"productLineId":"3G2D6R3YG85WZ570","createdTimestamp":"2018-08-20T18:53:46.435Z","inventoryLoadType":"HOT","variableInd":false,"isForcedResponseProduct":false,"reloadMinAmount":0,"entityId":"6APACRYFLXTLSKS","itemBuyerGroupId":"FASHION","provisioningType":"DIGITAL","productFulfillmentPartners":[],"currencyCode":"USD","proxyBin":"0"}',),)"""

json_str = dbresponse[3:-5]
data = json.loads(json_str)
print(data)

# {'stopApprovalInd': True, 'nonPersonalizedCardLine3': 'Valued Cardholder', 'productRoutingBins': [{'requestType': 'DIGITAL_ACCOUNT_REQUEST', 'bin': '342010002'}], 'holdtimeSeconds': 0, 'defaultUpcInd': 'false', 'updatedTimestamp': '2019-01-23T18:53:26.261Z', 'productName': "PB EGIFT (CASHSTAR) MACY'S $100", 'reloadMaxAmount': 0, 'issuerCompanyCode': ...

print(data['stopApprovalInd'])
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner content seems to be wrapped in single quote `'`, but contains unescaped single quotes (e.g. `"MAYO'S"`). This of course is a syntax error.

Despite the several levels of escaping seems the code that generated the content still isn't able to get it right.

As Thierry found however removing the first 4 and last 6 characters leaves a valid JSON (in this case) and you can parse it with `json.loads(dbresponse[4:-6])`.

Comment: I tried all the suggestions given so far and none of them worked. I was able to convert the tuple to str then got rid of the parenthesis so that all that was left was just json data.  tried `json.dumps` and `json.loads`.  neither worked.  I suspect the single quotes is causing an issue.  but why should it? i would imagine it'd be something python dictionary would automatically escape or handle? am I wrong?

Comment: @user2831586: First rule: don't panic. If python is telling you that `type(data)` is `tuple` then you're already halfway. The JSON string could be `data[0]` or may be `data[0][0]`; check which one is of type `str`. Once you get the `str` then just use `json.loads`. To recap the solution should be `json.loads(data[0][0])` or `json.loads(data[0])` (I'm suspecting `json.loads(data[0][0])` because what you have in the question is a string inside a one-element tuple inside another one-element tuple). The call `json.loads` should return your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

For support other types of inputs we can use `find` and `rfind`:

```
import json
# dbresponse = ...
begin = dbresponse.find("'")
end = dbresponse.rfind("'")

data = json.loads(dbresponse[begin+1:end])
```